# Flutter cloud storage can't upload files

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a file uploader using 'file_uploader' package. The file uploader package is loading the file properly but firebase_storage is not allowing me to upload files on the server.
Here is my code:

```
Future uploadFile() async {
  try {
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
   PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
   Uint8List fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  String fileName = result.files.first.name;
   print(file.name);
   print(file.bytes);
   print(file.size);
   print(file.extension);
   print(file.path);
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('documents/$file');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putData(fileBytes);
    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    print('File Uploaded');
   
    
  }
catch(e){
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}
```

It get triggered when a user hits the upload button. Here is my code that executes it:

```
RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: () {
            uploadFile();
  

     

      }, icon: Icon(Icons.description), label: Text('upload document')),
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
firebase_storage: ^3.1.1
file_picker: ^3.0.2+2
```

Comment: Could you please explain what’s going wrong? Is there an error message or the files are just not uploading to the Firebase storage?

Comment: It's showing <asynchronous_suspension> and the files are not getting uploaded on firebase storage.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5976